# How can I map only specific hubs in SignalR

Tags: c#-4.0, owin, signalr-hub

I have two hubs in my application. For the one I need NTLM authentication, and IP based filtering for the other. For this to work I need to set `HttpListener.AuthenticationSchemes` to `AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm` for the first, while it remains Anonymous for the other. This means that I can not have both hubs running on the same listener connection.
I have my `OwinMiddleware` to handle the authentication, and I am trying to set up two different endpoints for these two hubs (two different ports).

My problem is that when I don't know how to tell SignalR to map only a specific hub to specific `IAppBuilder`, and not all hubs that it can find. Any idea?

Comment: I am facing the same problem again. In this first case I managed it with webapi for the ntlm side. But now, I can't use this. Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this using custom `IAddemblyLocator`. I wrote an article about this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1237940/One-Possible-Way-of-Selectively-Assigning-Hubs-to

The basic idea is this:

```
using (WebApp.Start("http://*:8080", (app) => {
     var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
     var locator = new SingleAssemblyLocator(typeof(MyFirstHub).Assembly);

     resolver.Register(typeof(IAssemblyLocator), () => locator);
     app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { Resolver = resolver });
   }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Where `SingleAssemblyLocator.GetAssemblies()` is returning only the assembly passed to the constructor. Of course, each `WebApp` can be configured as needed.